# Rickshaw - need help designing line + bar toggle chart

Tags: charts, axes, rickshaw

I just started using Ricksaw for animated graphs and I'm trying to set up my x-axes to list months. Not in a particular time series (yet), but just to correspond with specific data points. I have a fairly simple coding program to try and do this but I can't seem to modify the x-axes labels. Is there an easy way to do this? Also, how would I do something similar for the y-axis? Thanks!

```js
< script >
  var myGraph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    element: document.querySelector("#mychart"),
    renderer: 'multi',
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    min: 0,
    max: 18,
    series: [{
      name: "Population1",
      color: "steelblue",
      renderer: 'lineplot',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 3,
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 8,
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 15,
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 12,
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 8,
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 3,
      }, {
        x: 7,
        y: 5,
      }, {
        x: 8,
        y: 2,
      }, {
        x: 9,
        y: 1,
      }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 4,
      }, ]
    }, {
      name: "Population2",
      color: "green",
      renderer: 'bar',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 5,
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 3,
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 8,
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 6,
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 3,
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 12,
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 13,
      }, {
        x: 7,
        y: 14,
      }, {
        x: 8,
        y: 12,
      }, {
        x: 9,
        y: 8,
      }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 9,
      }, ]
    }]
  });
var xTicks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
  graph: myGraph,
  orientation: "bottom",
  element: document.querySelector("#xaxis")
});
var yTicks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
  graph: myGraph,
  orientation: "left",
  element: document.querySelector("#yaxis")
});
var graphHover = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
  graph: myGraph
});
var myLegend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend({
  graph: myGraph,
  element: document.querySelector("#mylegend")
});
var toggling = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle({
  graph: myGraph,
  legend: myLegend
});
myGraph.render(); < /script>
```

```css
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.5.1/rickshaw.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.5.1/rickshaw.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:20px" id="mylegend"></div>
  <div style="display:block; float:left; width:20px; height:280px; padding-bottom:10px;" id="yaxis"></div>
  <div>
    <div style="margin-left:20px;" id="mychart"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:20px" id="xaxis"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
     graph: graph,
     tickFormat: function(x){
      return new Date(x).toLocaleString();
},
ticks: 4
});

xAxis.render();
```